2nd and 3rd display not working at the same time anymore
Yesterday I connected two new external monitors to my T14 notebook with Ubuntu 22/04.
It was working all day. After a restart I can use each of them separately but not at the same time.
I even can activate both in the display setting window. But after pressing "apply" only one of them is working and the other is deactivated automatically.
One of the displays is connected over USB-C including power supply. The other is connected with hdmi. (no other possible way to connect both since my second usb-c is not working.)
Between the last two restarts I did not install anything nor did I change something in the configuration of the system.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?
